# Download Remote File With Angular Using $http.get() - OAuth Authentication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-s3, oauth

My users have private files that need to be downloaded by an authenticated users. My server first downloads a file from S3 using it's own S3 app_id/secret_token credentials. The downloaded file is then constructed and sent to the client using Rails' [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) method.

Ruby (on Rails):

```
# documents_controller.rb
def download
  some_file = SomeFile.find(params[:id])

  # download file from AWS S3 to server
  data = open(some_file.document.url) 

  # construct and send downloaded file to client
  send_data data.read, filename: some_file.document_identifier, disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true'
end
```

Originally, I wanted to do trigger the download directly from the HTML template.

HTML:

```
<!-- download-template.html -->
<a target="_self" ng-href="{{ document.download_url }}" download="{{document.file_name}}">Download</a>
```

Looks simple enough but the problem is that Angular's $http interceptor doesn't catch this type of external link click and therefore the appropriate headers are not appended for server-side authentication. The result is a 401 Unauthorized Error.

Instead, I need to trigger the download using ng-click and then performing an $http.get() request from the angular controller.

HTML:

```
<!-- download-template.html -->
<div ng-controller="DocumentCtrl">
  <a ng-click="download(document)">Download</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// DocumentCtrl.js
module.controller( "DocumentCtrl",
  [ "$http", "$scope", "FileSaver", "Blob",
  function( $http, $scope, FileSaver, Blob ) {

    $scope.download = function( document ) {
      $http.get(document.download_url, {}, { responseType: "arraybuffer" } )
        .success( function( data ) {
          var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, document.file_name);
        });
    };
}]);
```

[FileSaver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) is a simple library to save files using Blobs (on the client, obviously).

This gets me passed by my authentication problem but results in the file being saved/download to the client in an unreadable/unusable format.

**Why is the file being downloaded in an unusable format?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use FileSaver?  Have you tried `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` and `window.open(objectUrl)`?

Comment: I don't need to use FileSaver but using window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob and window.open(objectUrl) both result in the same issue: an unreadable file format. It's still the case where the wrapped/constructed file is getting wrapped/constructed again by the Blob.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's $http method needs to be configured to accept a **binary data** response.

Rails' [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) documentation:

> Sends the given **binary data** to the browser. This method is similar to
>   render plain: data, but also allows you to specify whether the browser
>   should display the response as a file attachment (i.e. in a download
>   dialog) or as inline data. You may also set the content type, the
>   apparent file name, and other things.

Angular's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation is very poor regarding $http's configuration of **responseType**. Essentially, $http needs to be told to expect a **binary data** response by setting responseType to "arraybuffer" (see below).

```
$scope.download = function( document ) {
  console.log("download: ", document);
  $http({
    url: document.download_url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    responseType: "arraybuffer" // expect to handle binary data response
  }).success( function( data, status, headers ) {
      var type = headers('Content-Type');
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, document.file_name);
    });
};
```

Angular's [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) could be a little more descriptive than:

> Usage
>
> $http(config);
>
> Arguments
>
> config
>
> responseType - {string} - see [XMLHttpRequest.responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsetype).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have an example of how I download a file from my server with angular:

I call the file with GET request:

file download html(client side):

```
<a ng-href="/api/downloadFile/{{download.id}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 btn-modal-costume" >download</a>
```

file download java(server side):

```
public static Result download(String id) {
        String content = null;
        for (controllers.file file : files) {
            if (file.getId().equals(id)){
                content = file.getContent();
            }
        }
        return ok(new java.io.File("/temp/" + id+ "file" + content)).as("application/force-download");
    }
```

If you like you can see the all code in my [github project](https://github.com/ariel7342/m-book/blob/master/public/files/DownloadView.html)

Comment: Hi Ariel, Thanks for the response but <a ng-href="/api/downloadFile/{{download.id}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 btn-modal-costume" >download</a> still bypasses Angular's $http interceptor and therefore skips authentication.

Comment: in my code, I used restAngular , but in the file download case I had to use it that way, because if not it will return the file as a background request, and won't download it. or you need to move to new url just for the GET request and the download.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with the javascript solution, but just had a typo. In the `$http.get` call you pass an empty object as the second parameter. This is where the options argument with `{responseType: arraybuffer}` should have gone. See docs for `$http.get` here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get